# Software recommended for open source software testing project

Tags: open-source, software-testing, requirements-management

Wish that you all are having a good day, would like to ask for your kind opinions on whether there is any open source software(s) out there suitable to be used as a testing subject for an assignment assigned in the course of Software Testing.

It is recommended that the software has:

- At least 50 classes
- A use case documentation
- A user manual

The tasks assigned were mainly to get to study the software and formulate test plans, test design specifications and test case specifications using white box and black box techniques that will be performed to test the specific software, which the results will be recorded in a test log later.

Thanks for your time reading the post, any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please add what OS such software should run on – and whether [tag:open-source] shall also imply [tag:gratis] (e.g. "no cost involved")? Not that I have any solution in mind – but that would help to better fitting answers. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for software that already has extensive tests or software that you could potentially contribute tests for? Also which programming languages should the software be ideally written in? C/C++/C#/Python/PHP/BrainF*k/Lisp - the possibilities are endless. You also said __at least__ 50 classes - how about 50,000 or more? Some upper limit would make sense.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comments! Sorry I just noticed as I didn't receive email on this. So, it's basically an open-source software/tool to be referenced and studied. And the group shall later write test cases and test the software/tool, so no specific language needed and yea there is no any upper limit as well, because the testing of the APIs/functions will have a cap on it (regardless of the number of APIs/functions the tool has).
For instance, jQuery can be selected to be tested in this kind of assignment. Thanks once again.

Comment: As for the OS to be run on, the tool should be runnable on Windows, and whether it's gratis I would say that doesn't matter much, thanks!